# How to test the Business logic of an application developed using Angular2?

Tags: angular, testing, automation, protractor

I am looking for a solution considering End to End Testing of my application, more specifically testing the business logic developed using Angular2.

I will give some more details. I am using:
-Selenium using C# for the UI tests.
-Fitnesse for Back-end testing.

Thank you for all your suggestions.

Comment: This is what I have found on http://www.protractortest.org/#/
(Protractor is an end-to-end test framework for Angular and AngularJS applications.)

Comment: Your **business logic should not have dependencies** to Angular2 or any other frameworks.

Comment: Thank you Lovis for your suggestion.
I was looking on Pros vs Cons when using Protractor over Selenium-Webdriver.
http://testautomation.applitools.com/post/94994807787/protractor-vs-selenium-which-is-easier